# Running multiple commands in Python window for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am beginner at Python scripting and just started using it with ArcGIS Pro by executing commands in the Python window. However, I can only get one command to run at a time.

For example, if I enter the following lines of code in the Input Area of the python window and press "ENTER", the cursor moves to a new line in the input window instead of executing the commands.

```
arcpy.management.AddField("JanInt_200k_geo", "Uwt", "DOUBLE", 6, 10, None, None, "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", None)
arcpy.management.AddField("JanInt_200k_geo", "Vwt", "DOUBLE", 6, 10, None, None, "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", None)
arcpy.management.AddField("JanInt_200k_geo", "SO4", "DOUBLE", 15, 20, None, None, "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", None)
```

Is there a way to run multiple commands (i.e. a larger selection of my script) using this window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste your entire script into the python window and ArcGIS Pro will run the entire script.

Example: I have a streets layer and a rivers layer.  I want to buffer the river and clip the streets by that buffer using the following code

```
result = arcpy.Buffer_analysis("rivers", "riverBuf", "50 METERS")
print(result)
arcpy.Clip_analysis("streets", result, "streets_50m_of_rivers")
```

[image]

When I paste the code into the python pane and **press enter *twice*** the code will run.

[image]

The reason you need to hit enter twice is because when you paste a block of code arcpy allows you to add more code below it before running.  Once you hit enter again you're signalling that you are adding no more code, and you want arcpy to run it.

Alternatively you could attach your script to a script-tool and run your script from the geoprocessing pane.  This will also run your entire script.

Comment: When I paste in several lines into the Input Area and then press "ENTER", my cursor just moves to the next line in the Input Area instead of executing the command. I will update my question with a visual.

Comment: @ellejay press enter twice!  When you paste a block of code, pressing enter makes ArcGIS Pro think there may be more code that you're going to type in, so press it again to signal that you have no more code

Comment: Ah, thank you!!  Also, @Midavalo, could you elaborate on your comment below: "Alternatively you could attach your script to a script-tool and run your script from the geoprocessing pane. This will also run your entire script."  Alternatively, I can open another question - I am finding very few truly introductory resources that explain how to do this.

Comment: @ellejay It would probably require another question to ask about creating script-tools in ArcGIS Pro. There may already be questions here if you do a search, but to get you started try [Create a script tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/create-a-python-script-tool.htm) and [Adding a script tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/adding-a-script-tool.htm) on the ArcGIS Pro help/documentation site.